# When trying to use any ionic plugins getting error in nxtend/ionic-angular project

Tags: angular, ionic5, nrwl-nx

I am trying to use nxtend/ionic-angular in my project, But I got stuck while using plugins
1st use case : need to get a current app version
So I have installed these dependencies
1)npm install cordova-plugin-app-version 2) npm install @awesome-cordova-plugins/app-version
when I tried to run in android studio emulator getting bellow error
[image]

2nd use case need to use camera plugin similar error for camera plugin
[image]

package.json

````
{
"name": "anch",
"version": "0.0.0",
"license": "MIT",
"scripts": {
"start": "nx serve",
"build": "nx build",
"test": "nx test",
"postinstall": "ngcc --properties es2015 browser module main"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
"@angular/animations": "~13.3.0",
"@angular/common": "~13.3.0",
"@angular/compiler": "~13.3.0",
"@angular/core": "~13.3.0",
"@angular/forms": "~13.3.0",
"@angular/platform-browser": "~13.3.0",
"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~13.3.0",
"@angular/router": "~13.3.0",
"@awesome-cordova-plugins/app-version": "^5.41.0",
"@capacitor/camera": "^1.3.1",
"@capacitor/core": "^3.2.5",
"@capacitor/filesystem": "^1.1.0",
"@capacitor/storage": "^1.2.5",
"@ionic/angular": "^5.8.3",
"@ionic/pwa-elements": "^3.1.1",
"cordova-plugin-app-version": "^0.1.14",
"rxjs": "~7.4.0",
"tslib": "^2.0.0",
"zone.js": "~0.11.4"
},
"devDependencies": {
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~13.3.0",
"@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~13.1.0",
"@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "~13.1.0",
"@angular-eslint/template-parser": "~13.1.0",
"@angular/cli": "~13.3.0",
"@angular/compiler-cli": "~13.3.0",
"@angular/language-service": "~13.3.0",
"@capacitor/android": "^3.2.5",
"@capacitor/cli": "^3.2.5",
"@capacitor/ios": "^3.2.5",
"@nrwl/angular": "^13.0.0",
"@nrwl/cli": "14.0.2",
"@nrwl/cypress": "13.10.3",
"@nrwl/eslint-plugin-nx": "13.10.3",
"@nrwl/jest": "13.10.3",
"@nrwl/linter": "13.10.3",
"@nrwl/workspace": "14.0.2",
"@nxtend/capacitor": "^13.0.0",
"@types/jest": "27.0.2",
"@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "~5.18.0",
"@typescript-eslint/parser": "~5.18.0",
"cypress": "^9.1.0",
"eslint": "~8.12.0",
"eslint-config-prettier": "8.1.0",
"eslint-plugin-cypress": "^2.10.3",
"jest": "27.2.3",
"jest-preset-angular": "11.1.1",
"nx": "14.0.2",
"prettier": "^2.5.1",
"ts-jest": "27.0.5",
"typescript": "~4.6.2"
}
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

You have to add these plugins to app's `package.json`, not only monorepo's `package.json`.

First install the package as usual in your monorepo as you do with any other library, and then add the same entries in your app's `package.json`. You don't need to `npm install` in the app, just make sure these plugins are listed in both places. Then sync everything using `nx run my-app:cap --cmd=sync` (or however you run your capacitor commands). Plugins should be detected and referenced in native builds of your application.